# getting attributes of href using libxml

Tags: libxml2

I have xml file nameed Hello as under with starting node as under:

/*Hello xmlns:xsi: = "some text" xmlns:xsd = "some text" version="1.0"*/

I tried to get the first and second attributes of node named Hello, using

xmlAttr *attr = nodePtr->properties;//nurrent node is Hello

```
while ( attr )
{

    NSLog(@"\n Attribute name:%s value:%s",attr->name,attr->children->content);

    attr = attr->next;
};
```

But, i could not get the first and second attributes, instead it only returns third attribute. How can i get the first and second attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used libxml in a very long time, but you may need a different approach for accessing attributes which introduce new namespace prefixes. Atleast in XPATH etc they belong in a different "axis".

See for example the following two functions in the SAX based API

- [xmlSAX2StartElement](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-SAX2.html#xmlSAX2StartElement)
- [xmlSAX2StartElementNs](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-SAX2.html#xmlSAX2StartElementNs).

Comment: @Christopher Can you give some good links on tutorial to SAX interface for libxml.